# Is there a better alternative to check for collections with members with optional interfaces?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have a configuration registry class which holds a collection of configuration classes with a certain interface. These classes can also have an optional interface. So these classes may look like this in pseudocode:

```
class ConfigurationRegistry {   
    private ModuleConfiguration[];

    public function ConfigurationRegistry(ModuleConfiguration[] collection) {
       this.collection = collection;
    }

    public function getCollection() {
       return this.collection;
    }
}
```

```
class ConfigurationClass1 implements ModuleConfiguration, SpecificConfiguration {
    public function moduleMethod() {
       // do something
    }    

    public function specificMethod() {
       // do specific thing
    }
}
```

```
class ConfigurationClass2 implements ModuleConfiguration {
    public function moduleMethod() {
       // do something
    }    
}
```

```
public interface ModuleConfiguration {
    public function moduleMethod();
}
```

```
public interface SpecificConfiguration {
    public function specificMethod();
}
```

In my client code I would like to use these configuration classes. Sometimes I need the whole collection of configuration classes and sometimes I only need to collection of configuration classes which implement the `SpecificConfiguration` interface.

I could filter the collection method by using `instanceof` or I could loop through the collection and check whether the class implements the interface. But I've read quite a few articles stating online that using `instanceof` in this case is not considered a good practice.

My question is: is my implementation a good design? If not, do you have any suggestions how I could redesign or improve this?

Comment: From a strict oop point of view, you should always attempt to prefer polymorphism. But you are trying to have a heterogeneous collection, which could be easily model with union types in a functional programming language, but not in an oop one. About "how can I improve my design", it is not easy to answer. Why does the client code require to treat differently `ModuleConfiguration` and `SpecificConfiguration`? Why do you require `ConfigurationRegistry` to accept both of those types? Why do you require two types to begin with? etc.

Comment: @Federkun Thanks for commenting! The client code requires to treat the code differently because I would like to call certain services only with the values provided in the `SpecificConfiguration ` interface. These values are optional in the configuration classes and therefore I would like to filter the other ones out. I could merge the `SpecificConfiguration ` and the `ModuleConfiguration` interface into one interface but then the `SpecificConfiguration ` is not optional anymore.